# joomla: extend publish method through the controller

Tags: joomla2.5

I think my approach may be off, but this seems like a common need, so i'm hoping i'm not too far off.  Any input is appreciated.   When the 'publish/unpublish' button is clicked, i'd like to read 'getTask()' and take my own actions, after the core's 'publish' method completes.  Here's where I start:

In the controller, in my own 'publish' method i call parent::publish.  So far no problem.  Then I want to read getTask and pass it to the model function.

CONTROLLER_CLASS extends jCONTROLLER_ADMIN

```
public function publish()
{
    parent::publish();

    $model = $this->getModel();

    $myPublish = $this->getTask();
    $model->modelVariable = $myPublish;
    //or
    $model->doCustomPublishWork();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work out pretty well.

```
public function publish()
{
    $publishAffliate = $this->getTask();

    $cid = JRequest::getVar('cid');//affiliates DB record ID.

    $fileName = "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\conf\affilatesTest.txt";
    $fHandle = fopen($fileName, 'a');

    switch($publishAffliate)
    {
        case 'publish':
            fwrite($fHandle, "\npublished site ID = ". $cid[0]);
            break;
        case 'unpublish':
            fwrite($fHandle, "\nunpublished site ID = ". $cid[0]);
            break;
    }

    parent::publish();

}
```